# Unable to run struts program

Tags: java, struts2, glassfish

I developed one web applications using struts. Now when i tried to run in another machine I am getting the following error. Following is taken from glassfish server log

```
SEVERE:  INFO [http-thread-pool-8080-(1)] (CommonsLogger.java:31) - Parsing configuration file [struts-default.xml]

SEVERE:  INFO [http-thread-pool-8080-(1)] (CommonsLogger.java:31) - Unable to locate configuration files of the name struts-plugin.xml, skipping

SEVERE:  INFO [http-thread-pool-8080-(1)] (CommonsLogger.java:31) - Parsing configuration file [struts-plugin.xml]

SEVERE:  INFO [http-thread-pool-8080-(1)] (CommonsLogger.java:31) - Parsing configuration file [struts.xml]

SEVERE:  INFO [http-thread-pool-8080-(1)] (CommonsLogger.java:31) - Loading global messages from ApplicationResources
```

Also in the browser I am getting `java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException`this message. Please tell me where the problem lies.

Comment: Show more of the stack trace (or all of it).

Comment: @Sessizlik Nope. I tried several ways but no use. When I was trying same program in Ubuntu it worked. Have you solved it?

Comment: I havent also solved this problem. My application is working like a charm at Jetty, but not at Glassfish. My application have not been working at maven glassfish embedded v3 but working standalone glassfish server. I have noticed a few things too. First Spring could not find related configuration files which are at my classpath. Struts has same trouble. I think that there is a serious bug at classload or our applications is not completely loaded by container.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a similar problem to what is described in this article:

http://www.java.net/node/705006

It appears to be a GlassFish bug to *incorrectly* put "SEVERE:" before the log message that actually starts with "INFO".

FYI I came across this with SL4J and Glassfish 3.1. The exact same code logging via the JUL logger works perfectly, and then you get the "SEVERE:" when you swap it out with a proper logger.

Sadly I have not been able to find a resolution, and will post it when I find it. It is equally possible that they re-fix the bug in the next version of GlassFish.